# Why is my .appendRow from Array adding an extra row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I pretty much have the Apps Script file working as intended. However, each time it is triggered, it also adds a second line where the sessionEmail is not captured and is blank.

```
function onEdit() {
var sessionEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var spreadsheetTimeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
var lastUpdatedString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), spreadsheetTimeZone, "MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    if (s.getName() == "Workload") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if (r.getColumn() == 14) { //checks the column
            var status = r.getValue();
            var note = r.offset(0, -1);
            var noteValue = note.getValue()
            var delivery = r.offset(0, -5);
            var deliveryValue = delivery.getValue()
        }

        // Validating fields are filled in
        if (status == "Complete") {

            var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
            if (noteValue == '') { // if no note is entered, stop script with message box
                var noStatus = ui.alert(
                    'Warning!',
                    'Please enter notation before choosing Complete.',
                    ui.ButtonSet.OK);
                r.setValue('')
                return;
            }
            // get destination range

            var array = [lastUpdatedString, sessionEmail, deliveryValue, noteValue]
            var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
            var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Historical Notes Sheet");

          pasteSheet.appendRow(array)

            // clear response row
            note.setValue('')
            r.setValue('')
        }
    }
}
```

Image of what the results look like:
[image]

If any of you have any ideas on how to resolve this, and only append 1 line that has all the values, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Update:

Logging the variable produces the following (expected) results, where the e-mail address appeared in the string.
[image]

Results still populating 2 rows:
[image]

Comment: Can you `Logger.log(array)` just before the append and post it?

Comment: Hey @ChrisW, I have updated the OP with the logger image.

Comment: That is bizarre. Is there any other code that updates this sheet?

Comment: Nope! I've got it set to an onUpdate trigger. It should be looking for the word "Complete" to appear in column 14, then appending a couple of variables. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for helping me troubleshoot.

I went into View>Executions, and noticed that the script was running twice each time at about 2 milliseconds apart. I think the function name `onEdit()` was acting like an On Edit trigger, and causing the script to run with another On Edit trigger that I had set up for it.

I tried removing the trigger, and leaving it with the `onEdit()`name, but that was causing it to not grab the sessionEmail. Changing the code to the below, and adding the trigger back causes the code to run as expected.

```
function appendLine() {
var sessionEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().toString();
var spreadsheetTimeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
var lastUpdatedString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), spreadsheetTimeZone, "MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    if (s.getName() == "Workload") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if (r.getColumn() == 14) { //checks the column
            var status = r.getValue();
            var note = r.offset(0, -1);
            var noteValue = note.getValue()
            var delivery = r.offset(0, -5);
            var deliveryValue = delivery.getValue().toString();
        }

        // Validating fields are filled in
        if (status == "Complete") {
            var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
            if (noteValue == '') { // if no note is entered, stop script with message box
                var noStatus = ui.alert(
                    'Warning!',
                    'Please enter notation before choosing Complete.',
                    ui.ButtonSet.OK);
                r.setValue('')
                return;
            }

            // get destination range
            var array = [lastUpdatedString, sessionEmail, deliveryValue, noteValue]
            var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
            var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Historical Notes Sheet");
            pasteSheet.appendRow(array)

            // clear response row
            note.setValue('')
            r.setValue('')
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again to everyone for your help!